# PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL, The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired., {}, null))

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I faced an issue with email sign in method every time i test the app to login with invalid email I got an exception that told me PlatformExcepitnon Invalid Credentials Which i handled it in my login_Cubit class i have tried to update latest version of firebase_auth and firebase_core but still the issue same

```
 Future<void> loginWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
 emit(LoginLoading());
try {
  UserCredential userCredential =
      await _authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  emit(LoginSuccess(userCredential.user!));
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  // Handle Firebase exceptions
  String errorMessage = _handleFirebaseAuthException(e);
  emit(LoginFailure(errorMessage));
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  // Handle platform exceptions
  emit(LoginFailure(_handlePlatformException(e)));
} catch (e) {
  // Handle other exceptions
  emit(LoginFailure("An unexpected error occurred"));
  }
}

String _handlePlatformException(PlatformException e) {
// Handle specific platform exceptions
// The error handling here depends on the specific exceptions you expect
// For instance, handling Google Sign-In or Apple Sign-In errors
switch (e.code) {
  case 'ERROR_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_FAILED':
    return "Google sign-in failed. Please try again.";
  // ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL
  case 'ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL':
    return "Invalid Email Credentials.";
  // Add more cases as needed
  default:
    return "An error occurred on the platform side: ${e.message}";
  }
 }
```

this login screen

```
 body: BlocConsumer<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoginSuccess) {
            debugPrint('Login Is Succusseflly');
            context.goNamed(AppRoutes.bottomNavBarRoute);
          } else if (state is LoginFailure) {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                      actions: [
                        TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: const Text('Close'))
                      ],
                      title: const Text('Alert'),
                      icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/alert.svg'),
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      content: Text(state.error),
                    ));
          }
        }, builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoginLoading) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              final email = _emailController.text;
                              final password = _passwordController.text;
                              BlocProvider.of<LoginCubit>(context)
                                  .loginWithEmail(email, password);
                            }
```

Firebase auth

```
     Future<UserCredential> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
     String email, String password) async {
     return await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
     email: email, password: password);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Check Firebase Console Settings:
As mentioned in your provided information, make sure that email enumeration protection is not causing the issue. However, it's important to note that disabling email enumeration protection is not recommended for security reasons.

You can disable it by doing -

1. In the Firebase console, go to the **Firebase Auth Settings** page.

   a. In the navigation pane, select **User actions**.

   b. Clear **Email enumeration protection (recommended)**.
2. Click **Save**.

Documentation - https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection

Comment: I have tried this solution as you told me but it's same problem